# How to add draggable elements into fullcalendar event

Tags: javascript, ember.js, fullcalendar

I customized `eventContent` and added draggable elements inside of event. But the `dragstart` and `dragstop` event of the draggable elements are not emitting. It seems like the fullcalendar prevent other drag & drop inside of event.

```js
    this.element.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    this.element.addEventListener('dragstart', this.dragStart);
    this.element.addEventListener('dragend', this.dragEnd);
```

[image]

- **Blocking event dom**

[image]

Comment: Could you phrase what you wrote as a question? And could you build an example of the issue on Codepen, for example? Is it reproducible?

Comment: I want to do exactly that, did you find a way? If yes could you answer your own question here? If not I'll let you know if I found a solution.